# Mongoose, get child document and group by

Tags: javascript, sorting, mongoose, grouping

I'm trying to get some results and group the by an id, but I don't know a way to do that, I was trying with $unwind and $lookup, but when I use the $group, it doesn't give me results, so, I will appreciate any feedback.

usercalification model

```
{
 calification: Number,
 status: Number,
 place: {
   type: Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Place',
 }    
}
```

place model

```
{
 name: String,
 description: String
}
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
mongoose.model('usercalification').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'places',
            localField: 'place',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'places'
        }
    },
    {
        {
            $unwind: '$places'
        }
    }
]);
```

It works like it should, the issue is when I try to $groupBy

```
mongoose.model('usercalification').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'places',
            localField: 'place',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'places'
        }
    },
    {
        {
            $unwind: '$places'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$place',
            calification: { $avg: '$calification' },
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
]);
```

I'm grouping by $place cuz that's the Place Id that I need to group by.

I'll appreciate any feedback.

Comment: what does the object look like after unwind? maybe you have to group like `{$group:{_id : ."$place._id"..}}` you have to tell it which property of the object you want to group by. Maybe you gave it the whole place object.

Comment: It gives me the entire list, I mean if I have 10 records, it gives me 10 records with the place details. And if I try to group by $place._id, it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that those were not ordered in the correct way.